# leetcode subsets solution debugging

Tags: debugging

[subsets ii](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets-ii/)

basically you have to print all unique subsets. e.g. if `nums = [1,2,2]` then `res = [[], [1], [1, 2], [2], [2,2], [1,2,2]]`

my code gives `res = [[], [1], [1, 2], [2]]`

```
def subsets_dfs(nums):
    nums.sort()
    res = []
    def dfs(nums, res, cur, pos):
        res.append(cur)
        for i in range(pos, len(nums)):
            if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
                continue
            dfs(nums, res, cur + [nums[i]], i + 1)
    dfs(nums, res, [], 0)
    return res
```

Comment: Awful problem description in Leetcode. That's not even a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)t).

Answer (score 1):

In the if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i-1] , i > **0** should be **i > pos**

```
def subsets_dfs(nums):
    nums.sort()
    res = []
    def dfs(nums, res, cur, pos):
        res.append(cur)
        for i in range(pos, len(nums)):
            if i > pos and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
                continue
            dfs(nums, res, cur + [nums[i]], i + 1)
    dfs(nums, res, [], 0)
    return res
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Could you elaborate?

Comment: in this code, 'pos' means the depth of the recursion,  at current horizontal depth called pos level，we can select a num in nums[pos:len(nums)].for example [1,2,2,3] ,index from 0 to 3, when [1,2] in [1,2,2,3] has been selected, pos = 2, we can select a val in rest list [2,3], if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i-1], the 2 in [2,3] can't be selected because (i > 0 nums[2] == nums[1]).  i > pos determines  the selection range of the current horizontal layer